# How to convert a BufferedImage to 8 bit?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, 8-bit

I was looking at the ImageConverter class, trying to figure out how to convert a BufferedImage to 8-bit color, but I have no idea how I would do this. I was also searching around the internet and I could find no simple answer, they were all talking about 8 bit grayscale images. I simply want to convert the colors of an image to 8 bit... nothing else, no resizing no nothing. Does anyone mind telling me how to do this.

Comment: You probably have to choose a quantization algorithm, ie. something that transform the range of colors of your images into a 256 entry palette.

Comment: What do you mean by converting the colors of an image to 8-bit? I guess you want to reduce the color space? Do you want to perform Color quantization?

Comment: Could you guys point me to a library/API of some sort? I have no idea what you're talking about. That also sounds like I would be able to create my own palette which would be event better if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet from the article ["Transparent gifs in Java" at *G-Man's Uber Software Engineering Blog*](http://gman.eichberger.de/2007/07/transparent-gifs-in-java.html) works well:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage src = convertRGBAToIndexed(ImageIO.read(new File("/src.jpg")));
    ImageIO.write(src, "gif", new File("/dest.gif"));
}

public static BufferedImage convertRGBAToIndexed(BufferedImage src) {
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
    Graphics g = dest.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(231, 20, 189));

    // fill with a hideous color and make it transparent
    g.fillRect(0, 0, dest.getWidth(), dest.getHeight());
    dest = makeTransparent(dest, 0, 0);

    dest.createGraphics().drawImage(src, 0, 0, null);
    return dest;
}

public static BufferedImage makeTransparent(BufferedImage image, int x, int y) {
    ColorModel cm = image.getColorModel();
    if (!(cm instanceof IndexColorModel))
        return image; // sorry...
    IndexColorModel icm = (IndexColorModel) cm;
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    int pixel = raster.getSample(x, y, 0); // pixel is offset in ICM's palette
    int size = icm.getMapSize();
    byte[] reds = new byte[size];
    byte[] greens = new byte[size];
    byte[] blues = new byte[size];
    icm.getReds(reds);
    icm.getGreens(greens);
    icm.getBlues(blues);
    IndexColorModel icm2 = new IndexColorModel(8, size, reds, greens, blues, pixel);
    return new BufferedImage(icm2, raster, image.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
}
```

Comment: Worked great, just had to remove the transparency part.

Answer (score 5):

You can use JAI (Java Advanced Imaging), the official Sun (now Oracle) image library to do that.

The [ColorQuantizerDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/ColorQuantizerDescriptor.html) shows the choice of quantization processes you can apply.

Comment: Do you have some sample code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312921/how-to-use-colorquantizerdescriptor

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `convert8` method in the `ConvertUtil` class.

For details have a look [here](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html?net/sf/image4j/util/ConvertUtil.html).

Comment: I could not use ConvertUtil.convert8, so I would have to import that class, but I could not find what the import code was. Do you by chance do what/where it is?